# browserify/karma/angular.js "TypeError: Cannot read property '$injector' of null" when second test uses "angular.mock.inject", "currentSpec" is null

Tags: karma-runner, browserify, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

I have an Angular.js app and am experimenting with using it with Browserify. The app works, but I want to run tests too, I have two jasmine tests that I run with karma. I user browserify to give me access to angular.js and angular-mocks.js and other test fixtures within the tests.

Versions are:-

```
"angular": "^1.4.0",
"angular-mocks": "^1.4.0",
"browserify": "^10.2.3",
"karma": "^0.12.32",
"karma-browserify": "^4.2.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.12",
"karma-coffee-preprocessor": "^0.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^0.3.5",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
```

If I run the tests individually (by commenting one or the other from the karma.conf file) they both work OK. (yey!)

But if I run them both I get this error

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property '$injector' of null
    at Object.workFn (/tmp/3efdb16f2047e981872d82fd8db9c0a8.browserify:2272:22 <- node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2271:0)
```

looking at line 2271 of the angular.mocks.js It reads

```
if (currentSpec.$injector) {
```

So clearly currentSpec is somehow now null.

I have isolated the problem to when I call "angular.mock.inject" in the second test.

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_GridUtilService_) {
  gridUtilService = _GridUtilService_;
}));
```

If I comment this out it works, but obviously I can't then run a test n my gridUtilService.

**Does anyone know how to run two (or more :-) angular-mock jasmine tests with karma and browserify?**

below are my tests, karma.conf file. the Angular services work when deployed but for this purpose they can simply be dumb services that do nothing.

karma.conf:-

```
// Karma configuration

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['browserify', 'jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'src/main/assets/js/**/*.js',
//      'src/test/**/*.js'
      'src/test/services/SettingUtil*.js',
      'src/test/services/GridUtil*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
        'src/main/assets/js/**/app-config.js'
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      'src/main/assets/js/**/*.js': ['browserify'],
      'src/test/**/*.js': ['browserify']
    },

    browserify: {
        debug: true,
        extensions: ['.js', '.coffee', '.hbs']
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
//    browsers: ['PhantomJS', 'Chrome'],
//    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

src/test/services/SettingUtilServiceTest.js:

```
'use strict';

describe("SettingUtilServiceTest.", function() {
  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });

  require('angular');

  require('angular-mocks'); 

  // can't do below see error at https://github.com/xdissent/karma-browserify/issues/10
  //beforeEach(module('dpServices'));

  //so need todo this
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('dpServices'));

  var fixtures = require('./serviceFixtures.js');

  var sus = fixtures.settingUtilServiceTestFixtures;
  var ts1 = sus.tablesetting1;
  var ts2 = sus.tablesetting2;

  var settingUtilService;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_settingUtilService_) {
      settingUtilService = _settingUtilService_;
    }));

    it('should return an object containing mins and maxs from function minMaxes()', function() {
        expect(ts1).toBeDefined();
        expect(ts2).toBeDefined();
        var minMaxs = settingUtilService.minMaxs(ts1);
        var mins = minMaxs.mins;
        expect(mins).toBeDefined();
        var maxs = minMaxs.maxs;
        expect(maxs).toBeDefined();
    });

});
```

src/test/services/GridUtilServiceTest.js:

```
'use strict';

describe("GridUtilServiceTest.", function() {
  it("is a set of tests to test GridUtilService.", function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });

  require('angular');

  require('angular-mocks');

  // can't do below see error at https://github.com/xdissent/karma-browserify/issues/10
//  beforeEach(module('dpServices'));

  //so need todo this
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('dpServices'));

  var fixtures = require('./gridFixtures.js');

  var gridFix = fixtures.gridUtilServiceTestFixtures;

  var ts1 = gridFix.tablesetting1;
  var ts2 = gridFix.tablesetting2;
  var ts3 = gridFix.tablesetting3;

  var gridUtilService;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_GridUtilService_) {
    gridUtilService = _GridUtilService_;
  }));

  it('should return an object containing mins and maxs from function minMaxes()', function() {
        expect(ts1).toBeDefined();
        expect(ts2).toBeDefined();
        expect(ts3).toBeDefined();
    });

});
```

If you need access to the angular setup I can provide it (split into multiple files using browserify's require() function and built with gulp... but as I say the app runs ok and the tests only fail when there are two tests, so I think the issue is with karma-jasmine and angular-mocks or overwriting the `currentSpec` variable.

If anyone knows how to split my angular tests into multiple tests (I don't want a monolithic angular test) without the error message all help is appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, the issue for me was because I was requiring angular and angular-mocks exactly as you were inside each describe block. I moved the two lines

```
require('angular');
require('angular-mocks');
```

above the describe blocks and made sure to only call them once.

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a try and upvote you if it works :-)